# Solve nonlinear equation system with parameter in Matlab

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-functions

How to modify the code if I add parameter c to function
Thank for help

```
x0 = [0,0];
x = fsolve(@myfunc,x0)
%===================
function F = myfunc(x)
F(1) = 4*c*(c*x(1) - 2)^3 + 2*c*x(2)^2 *(c*x(1)-2);
F(2) = 2*x(2)*(cx(1) - 2)^2 + 2*(x(2)+1);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the function line as following: `function F = myfunc(x, c)`
2. Change `x` execution part:

```
x = fsolve(@(x) myfunc(x, c), x0)
```

3. Create a new function `x(c)`:

```
function x = x_func(c)
    x0 = [0,0];
    x = fsolve(@(x) myfunc(x, c), x0);
end
```

4. Use your inputs:

```
c = 6;
x = x_func(c);
x1 = 2/c;
x2 = -1;
```

Comment: This is not what I want because c=6. I want x = x(c). The solution x1=2/c and x2 = -1

Comment: @taolao, updated. I hope I've understood you.

Comment: I do not understand your solution. The problem is how to solve the equation system with parameter c. Of course x = x(c). The above problem if we solved you will see that it has solution x1=2/c and x2 = -1. And I want the Matlab code to have them.